# Performing Entities relational fix up myself, instead of waiting on Entity Framework SaveContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given the following over-simplified code:

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

In my consumer code, I'd have:

```
 parent.Children.Add(child);
```

This does not set the child.Parent, until I call db.SaveContext();

I see situations in which this is a problem, e.g. chaining a couple of operations on the same object before saving.

My question is, should I be doing this instead:

```
 class Child
 {
      public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

      public void SetParent(Parent parent) {
         if (this.Parent != null) { this.Parent.Children.Remove(this); }

         parent.Children.Add(this);
         this.Parent = parent;
      }
 }
```

Please note the code snippet is just for illustrative purpose.

Generally my question is, should I handle the relational fix up myself, instead of relying on EF.

Comment: why would you want to handle that? what is your concern?

Comment: My concern is that unless I `save`, the object is not in a correct state. It just seems wrong to rely on EF to fix the mess.

Comment: It is not the mess. You just don't know the Ids of the entities.
If I remember correctly - ef with ObjectContext (prior to dbContext) was douing all that - referencing other sides of nav properties, assigning Ids (if known) etc.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I would try to avoid the kind of chained operations that would require you to have to do this, but I don't think there is anything wrong with doing it if you need it.

A suggestion: Do not directly expose the `Children` collection in your `Parent` class, make its setter method private or protected, and add methods to add and remove `Children` elements in the `Parent` class. This is the way to ensure that the logic to set `Child` parent is always executed whenever the collection changes.

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; protected set; }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        Children.Add(child);
        child.Parent = this;
    }

    public void RemoveChild(Child child)
    {
        Children.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but making the `setter` non-public does not protect the collection from changes. On the other hand, we can't have `IReadOnlyCollection` as EF navigational property. Stalemate.

Comment: The goal is not to protect the collection against changes, but to make sure the required `child.Parent = newParent` gets executed when those changes happen. And EF can deal with navigation properties with only a public getter. Try this: `public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; } = new HashSet<Child>();`

Comment: Having the two methods `AddChild`and `RemoveChild` without protecting the `Children` property is like putting a solid door in the middle of a grass field.

Comment: Then protect the property. You can map private properties as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13810766/1182515).

Comment: [Here](https://owencraig.com/mapping-but-not-exposing-icollections-in-entity-framework/) you have a way to do it, exposing a truly protected `Children` property where you can only add elements through the `AddChild` method.