# Why do Entity Framework Core POCOs returned from a DbQuery have to be public?

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard, access-modifiers

I'm using a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbQuery` to return POCOs from the result of a table-valued function in my database.  I noticed that none of my POCOs have any of their properties set -- they're all default values -- as long as their access modifiers are anything other than `public`.  In my case, the POCOs are all implementing interfaces explicitly so the consumer doesn't (or shouldn't) know anything about the POCO definitions so I want to set them to `internal`.

Why do the POCOs have to be public?  Or, is there a way to make it so they don't have to be public?  Here is some sample code to demonstrate this:

***CoreLibrary.dll (.NET Standard 2.0)***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CoreLibrary
{
    public interface IWidgetRepository
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<IWidget> FindAllWidgets();
        IReadOnlyCollection<IWidget> FindWidgets(string withText);
    }

    public interface IWidget
    {
        int ID { get; }
        string Name { get; }
        string Value { get; }
    }
}
```

***DataAccess.dll (.NET Standard 2.0)***

```
using CoreLibrary;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public sealed class WidgetRepositoryApi : IWidgetRepository
    {
        private DatabaseContext _dbContext;

        public WidgetRepositoryApi(string databaseServerName, string databaseName)
            => _dbContext = new DatabaseContext(databaseServerName, databaseName);

        public IReadOnlyCollection<IWidget> FindAllWidgets()
            => _dbContext.Widget.ToList();

        public IReadOnlyCollection<IWidget> FindWidgets(string withText)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_SearchWidgetText(@Text)";

            var ret = _dbContext.GetWidgetFullTextSearchMatches
                .FromSql(sqlQuery, new SqlParameter("@Text", 
                System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = withText });

            return ret.ToList().AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    internal partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        private string _dbConnectionString;

        internal DatabaseContext(string databaseServerName, string databaseName) 
            => _dbConnectionString = 
            $"Server={databaseServerName};Database={databaseName};Trusted_Connection=True;";

        internal virtual DbSet<DBSetWidget> Widget { get; set; }

        internal virtual DbQuery<DBQueryWidget> GetWidgetFullTextSearchMatches { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_dbConnectionString);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DBSetWidget>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Value).IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }

    /********************************************************************
     * NOTE: there need to be two widget implementations (POCOs)
     * because otherwise the code throws
     * System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
     * 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.
     * InternalDbQuery`1[DataAccess.DBSetWidget]' to type 
     * 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[DataAccess.DBSetWidget]'.'
     *******************************************************************/

    internal partial class DBQueryWidget : IWidget
    {
        internal int Id { get; set; }
        internal string Name { get; set; }
        internal string Value { get; set; }
        int IWidget.ID => Id;
        string IWidget.Name => Name;
        string IWidget.Value => Value;
    }

    internal partial class DBSetWidget : IWidget
    {
        internal int Id { get; set; }
        internal string Name { get; set; }
        internal string Value { get; set; }
        int IWidget.ID => Id;
        string IWidget.Name => Name;
        string IWidget.Value => Value;
    }
}
```

***ConsumerConsoleApp.exe (.NET Core 2.1)***

```
using DataAccess;

namespace ConsumerConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var repo = new WidgetRepositoryApi(args[0], args[1]);
            var allWidgets = repo.FindAllWidgets();
            var someWidgets = repo.FindWidgets("facebook");
        }
    }
}
```

***Widget Table in SQL Database***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Widget](
[ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
[Value] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Widget] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

***fn_SearchWidgetText in database***

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SearchWidgetText]
(   
    @Text NVARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Widget
    WHERE CONTAINS(Value, @Text)
)
```

[image]

[image]

If I change all my access modifiers in my `DataAccess` namespace to `public`, now the POCOs get filled properly:

[image]

Comment: They really don't have to be public. Please show an example in which properties of entity objects aren't set. I can't imagine how EF would manage to materialize entity objects without setting their property values.

Comment: How could I show that?  You'd need the database to test it.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a just one class + interface + mapping combination that behaves the way you describe. For testing we can let EF generate a database.

Comment: @GertArnold -- I've played around with it and narrowed things down a bit.  Please see the updates.

Comment: You are putting too much OOP into something that is supposed to be simple storage model. If you want to process such entities generically with EF (e.g. generic methods with interface constrains), the interfaces must be implemented implicitly (publicly). Since your classes are `internal`, I don't see why shouldn't their properties be `public`. `internal` modifier on properties of `internal` class does not make them more internal.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is just because it's by design.

The observation is a state of any object can be split into two parts. The first part is public state, and the second part is internal state of the object. When you design data store technology you should decide what you want to store. Only one part or both? EF is designed to store almost any object (which can have complicated internal structure) in relatively simple database. So, is a good assumption to ignore internal structure of objects.

Comment: I see your point, but it would still be nice to override the default behavior and maybe instead of configuration by convention we could use attributes to signal the members that EF should care about.

Comment: You can try something like it https://romiller.com/2012/10/01/mapping-to-private-properties-with-code-first/

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807406/entity-framework-many-to-many-through-containing-object/13810766#13810766

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I've learned a lot about the intricacies of this issue since I posted the OP.  If it's "by design" then it's not consistent, since the POCOs returned by `DbSet` work just fine, just not when returned by a `DbQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework core doesn't map internal properties by its default conventions. The only difference between `DBQueryWidget` and `DBSetWidget` is that for the latter you have an explicit mapping instruction:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DBSetWidget>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    entity.Property(e => e.Value).IsRequired();
});
```

For `DBQueryWidget` there's no such mapping, and therefore EF follows its default convention and doesn't map its internal properties. So the only thing you need to fix this is to add a similar mapping for `DBQueryWidget`.