# Entity framework map placeholder value to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In a legacy database, `NULL` values are sometimes stored as the string NULL and/or "x".

How can I tell EF that I want it to automatically convert those "placeholder values" to `NULL`?

**Update**:
I want to avoid ambiguity / accidental complexity in my model by having the same property twice. (If people can get/set `LegacyColumn`, they will and abstraction is broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new property based on the existing property that is not mapped to the database and that performs the desired conversion. Assuming the column is named `Foo` you can use this code:

```
[Column("Foo")]
public String FooWithWeirdNullValues { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public String Foo {
  get {
    return FooWithWeirdNullValues == "NULL" || FooWithWeirdNullValues == "x"
      ? null : FooWithWeirdNullValues;
  }
  set { FooWithWeirdNullValues = value; }
}
```

In your code you then use the unmapped property to access the value of the `Foo` column.

You might want to pick another name for `FooWithWeirdNullValues` e.g. `LegacyFoo` or whatever. You can pick any name as long as you use the `Column` attribute to map it to the correct column in the database.

If desired you can make `FooWithWeirdNullValues` private to not pollute your model. This requires a few changes to the `DbContext` as described in [an answer on Stack Overflow on how to map private properties using code first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21686896/98607).

Comment: This would pollute my model :(. In NHibernate this can be achieved quite easily, I'm surprised EF does not have this?
I was hoping `EditorBrowsable(Never)` would solve that but it doesn't.

Comment: @Laoujin: I have updated my answer with some additional information that might address your concern about polluting the model.